# Best way to pass multiple lambda functions in Kotlin to handle success/failure

Tags: android, kotlin

New at Kotlin here and trying to learn the best way to use the higher order functions and passing lambdas. I've created this method to call an API and return an object created from a string OR return a failure if something went wrong.

```
    fun getDeviceStatus(onSuccess: (Device) -> Unit, onFailure: ((String) -> Unit)? = null) {

        FuelClient.get(DEVICE_URL,
                success = { responseString ->

                    val adapter = MoshiUtil.moshi.adapter(Device::class.java)

                    val deivce= adapter.fromJson(responseString)!!

                    onSuccess(device)
                },
                failure = { onFailure?.invoke(it.message!!)})


    }
```

I can use this function fine like so:

```
DeviceService.getDeviceStatus(
                { w ->
                    print("device")
                },
                { e -> print(e) })
```

But it bothers me a bit that I can't see the name of the functions to see what each function does. I"m wondering if there is a cleaner/better way to do this, like

```
DeviceService.getDeviceStatus(){
            onSuccess{print("device")}
            onFailure{print("error")}
        }
```

or maybe

```
DeviceService.getDeviceStatus()
                .onSuccess{print("device")}
                .onFailure{print("error")}
```

But those gives errors. Any thoughts on how to best handle the onSuccess/onFailure use case that is very common? Thx

Comment: You can do as suggested in Suhaib's answer, or also use something like Promises from Kovenant library which specifically has nice ways of dealing with success/failure.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can attach a name to each variable in kotlin. Change your code like this

```
DeviceService.getDeviceStatus(
                onSuccess = { w ->
                    print("device")
                },
                onFailure = { e -> print(e) })
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems there are multiple ways to handle this and I'm not sure which one I like best, but this is a good start.

Comment: If anyone is looking for a better explanation on different ways to handle this, I found this article particularly helpful: https://antonioleiva.com/listeners-several-functions-kotlin/

Comment: The problem with named arguments is that it doesn't force the developer to use them, making things a big ambigous

Answer (score 4):

For example we have a class which needs to have more than one function such as two functions as parameter:

```
class TestClass internal constructor(
  private val onClickShowName: (String) -> Unit,
  private val onClickShowSurname: (String) -> Unit
) { //Your work. }
```

Then you need to create val as TestClass:

```
class MainActivity {
    val mTestClass = TestClass(
        onClickShowName = {dataText: String -> Log.i("TEST", dataText)},
        onClickShowSurname = {dataText: String -> Log.i("TEST", dataText)}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case, when the second lambda is optional, `infix` functions work very well:

```
sealed class DeviceStatusResult {
    abstract infix fun onFailure(handler: (String) -> Unit)
}

class DeviceStatusSuccess(val device: Device) : DeviceStatusResult() {
    override fun onFailure(handler: (String) -> Unit) = Unit
}

class DeviceStatusFailure(val errorMessage: String) : DeviceStatusResult() {
    override fun onFailure(handler: (String) -> Unit) = handler(errorMessage)
}

fun getDeviceStatus(onSuccess: (Device) -> Unit): DeviceStatusResult {
    // get device status
    // if (success)
    val device = Device()
    onSuccess(device)
    return DeviceStatusSuccess(device)
    // else
    // return DeviceStatusFailure(message)
}
```

Then it can used like

```
getDeviceStatus { device ->
    println(device)
} onFailure { errorMessage ->
    System.err.println(errorMessage)
}
```

Maybe `onFailure` should be called `orFail` or something like that.

It is good when the second argument is optional, but not so much otherwise because it doesn't force the user to actually supply a failure handler. And I don't think it's a good idea because it will be too easy to accidentally omit a failure handler. It's much better to force the user to provide one, even if it happens to be an empty one. Therefore, it is better to use named arguments for this case, even though nothing forces to actually name them.